# repeat a div twice horizontally

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want such format using bootstrap row and col.
[image]

I have tried many ways...below is the last code

```
         <div class="row">
            <form name="" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div>
                        <label><strong>{{Heading}}}</strong></label>
                        <Textarea>
                           <span ng-bind=""></span>
                        </Textarea>
                    </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Please Suggest

Comment: Are you using ```angular js```? If so post your complete code including ```ng-repeat```..

Comment: <div ng-repeat="order in orders|orderBy:'sequence'" ng-show="condition">
         <div class="row">
            <form name="" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div>
                        <label><strong>{{Heading}}}</strong></label>
                        <Textarea>
                           <span ng-bind=""></span>
                        </Textarea>
                    </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

Comment: Does this is what you want?? https://plnkr.co/edit/6vF7iEbn9ZCB9M9mfDfX

Comment: i dont have iteration on form since outside form control are also using iteration values

Answer (score 0):

https://codepen.io/Dooomel/pen/OJVgpzp

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      th1
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      th2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      th3
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      th4
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Btw. You don't need to set class for every breakpoint, col-sm-6 is passed to md and lg

Comment: i am using ng-repeat for this data population.combination of label and textarea should get repeated twice in a row.this form should get repeated using bootstrap

Comment: Then you should put the iteration inside row class and for every pair of label and textarea create a div with class col-sm-6. I updated the pen so you can see how the wrapping happens inside row

Comment: its still not repeated horizontally...going vertically as before

Answer (score 0):

Please checkout this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js">
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" class="row">
   <form name="" class="col-6" ng-repeat="x in [1,2,3,4,5, 6]">
     <div><b>{{Heading}}</b></div>
     <Textarea></Textarea>
   </form>
<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.Heading='Place holder';
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: iteration is being used outside form tag since its needed for other fields

Comment: You mean you want form to repeat ?

Comment: <div ng-repeat="order in orders|orderBy:'sequence'" ng-show="condition">
         <div class="row">
            <form name="" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div>
                        <label><strong>{{Heading}}}</strong></label>
                        <Textarea>
                           <span ng-bind=""></span>
                        </Textarea>
                    </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

Comment: like above,iteration is happening in div which is outside form. yes form should be repeated

Comment: Please check it now. Form will be repeated.